# Using a slash in Slim

Tags: slim-lang

I have the following code that's causing a `Slim::Parser::SyntaxError`:

```
p
  code.inline /charge
```

I expect this to output `<code class="inline">/charge</code>` but it's just causing Slim to get upset.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it using the escape character `'`, like so:

```
p
  code.inline
    '/charge
```

Hacky, but whatever .. it works.